# Adding Service reference does not generate endpoints in app.config file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, soap

I have been referencing the SOAP services for a while and I never came across a problem like this. I added the service reference and expected it to update my config file. It actually did not.

as mentioned in here
[Visual Studio does not generate app.config content when "add service reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159107/visual-studio-does-not-generate-app-config-content-when-add-service-reference)

I also followed the steps of going to advanced and unchecking "Reused Types in referenced assemblies". That also did not work.

Anything else that I can do to make it work? May there be something wrong with the service itself? How do I figure that out?

Comment: What kind of service are you trying to load up?  Add Reference sometimes doesn't work on newer services or with those containing mystifying configurations (such as making a WCF service with restful URLs).

Comment: @bvoyelr: Good Point but wouldn't the fact that it has a WSDL tell us that it is basically a SOAP? How do I confidently say that it is SOAP or REST?

Comment: I don't remember good old SOAP web service adding anything to app.config. It adds all necessary components under service reference.

Comment: @bvoyelr: I think I am a little mor einclined to believe that it is s SOAP because when i added the service reference, it created `Reference.CS`. If it was a REST, this would had never happened. What do you think?

Comment: @T.S.: Probably But when I create a client and then run the project then it is looking for <ServiceModel> section in the config file.

Comment: Than you don't use SOAP WebServices - you use WCF and possibly SOAP protocol. Your description is confusing because you said "I have been referencing the SOAP services..." but that is not what you have

Comment: Here is your answer to this  [Why is the <system.serviceModel> section missing from app.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231086/why-is-the-system-servicemodel-section-missing-from-app-config)

Comment: @CoffeeBean You mentioned Reference.cs -- I take it that file is empty as well?

Comment: @bvoyelr: Well, no tit generates references.cs BUT just it is not able to update the config files. Actually, I was able to make some progress further. It turned it that is is Java SOAP Service and I am trying to reference it to .Net environment. Nto sure that is the main reason why is is not updating app.config file. However, when I add it as a "Web Reference" as oppose to the service reference, it updates the config file and I am able to communicate to it. Not sure why I need to add it as a "Web reference" though?

Comment: If someone can explain why, Please add it to the answer section and I will be able to mark it as a final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. It was not the regular C# based SOAP service and it is basically **SalesForce/SuccessFactor** API. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/09/accessing-force-com-soap-endpoints-net.html) is the document which will be able to give more details on this.

I am not sure **why** we should use Web Reference as oppose to Service Reference. I can only confirm the fact that using Web reference works and adding Service reference does not.

I am very curious on **WHY** part of it. If someone can explain please add your comments in an answer and I will be happy to mark it as an answer.